# Take sample from diminishing population

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to take a random sample of rows from a data.frame, apply a function to the subset, then take a sample from the remaining rows, apply the function to the new subset (with different parameters), and so on.

A simple example would be if 5% of a population dies each month, in month 2 I need the population minus those ones who died in time month 1.

I have put together a very verbose method of doing this involving where I save the IDs from the sampled rows, then subset them out from the data for the second period, etc.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Number=1:100, ID=paste0("A", 1:100))


first<-dt[sample(nrow(dt), nrow(dt)*.05)]$ID
mean(dt[ID %in% first]$Number)


second<-dt[!(ID %in% first)][sample(nrow(dt[!(ID %in% first)]),
                                 nrow(dt[!(ID %in% first)])*.05)]$ID
mean(dt[ID %in% c(first,second)]$Number)

dt[!(ID %in% first)][!(ID %in% second)] #...
```

Obviously, this is not sustainable past a couple periods. What is the better way to do this? I imagine this is a standard method but couldn't think what to look for specifically. Thanks for any and all input.

Comment: That would be fine, but how can I generate those groups as outlined above? That is, a random subset from the initial population, then another random subset from the population minus subset1, etc.

Comment: Think about what your actual problem is. Do you really want to simulate (a) exactly 5% of the population dying or (b) a 5% chance of each member of the population dying? Alternatively, do you want to consider each member as a fractional life and carry forward the probability of each person still being alive?

Comment: Well, that's not really what I'm looking at, just a simple way to frame it. And either way, don't I still need to remove the "dead" observations from my population each time period? Can you point me to something relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to "grow" a vector of items that have been sampled at a 5% per interval time course:

```
 removed <- numeric(0)
 for ( i in 1:10){ 
    removed <- c(removed, sample( (1:100)[!(1:100) %in% removed], # items out so far
                                  (100-length(removed))*.05))  # 5% of remainder
     cat(c(removed, "\n"))  # print to console with each iteration.
     }
54 1 76 96 93 
54 1 76 96 93 81 16 13 79 
54 1 76 96 93 81 16 13 79 80 74 30 29 
54 1 76 96 93 81 16 13 79 80 74 30 29 52 33 86 19 
54 1 76 96 93 81 16 13 79 80 74 30 29 52 33 86 19 34 32 41 62 
54 1 76 96 93 81 16 13 79 80 74 30 29 52 33 86 19 34 32 41 62 5 70 8 
54 1 76 96 93 81 16 13 79 80 74 30 29 52 33 86 19 34 32 41 62 5 70 8 66 82 50 
54 1 76 96 93 81 16 13 79 80 74 30 29 52 33 86 19 34 32 41 62 5 70 8 66 82 50 6 91 99 
54 1 76 96 93 81 16 13 79 80 74 30 29 52 33 86 19 34 32 41 62 5 70 8 66 82 50 6 91 99 46 27 51 
54 1 76 96 93 81 16 13 79 80 74 30 29 52 33 86 19 34 32 41 62 5 70 8 66 82 50 6 91 99 46 27 51 22 23 20
```

Notice that the actual number of items added to the list of "removals" will be decreasing.